# OS X Leopard profile hangs on load

Tags: leopard

ON a current project, and really need help. Re-install would be a painful option right now.

Running OS X 10.5.8 and just downloaded and reinstalled compbo update.

Yesterday installed latest version of evernote and now having all types of problems. Don't think it was evernote, but actually GROWL.

If I login in with my creds, it takes over 20 min to load my profile. If I login with dummy acct, it loads in less than 2 min. Applications launch but every couple of mins hangs for @ 4-5 min.

Ran permmisstions repair and disk repair twice. Some problems where found but fixed.

Disabled all startup apps from Accounts. What else can I do?

EDIT - 
Just started in verbose mode again and ran /sbin/fsck -fy again.  the same error came out.  After Checing Catalog file, it said Incorrect block count for file 2011.04.18.U501.asl (It should be 734 instead of 367).

Comment: Have you tried deleting evernote/growl? Do you have the install DVD? (To perform a full disk repair) I dont think growl can have such an effect on a mac.  Do you have an external hard-drive with a Time Machine Backup? I suggest getting one, for occasions like this one. I never thought Id need it, but it saved my life a couple months ago...

Comment: Did uninstall evernote and Growl. Some time ago, some other app wanted to install Growl causing similar issue. Thought it was fixed but obviously not. Now I can not even login to my profile. It just hangs with the beach ball of "death"... :(

Comment: How long have you had your mac? .asl files are generally the result of logging, and if you had a user specific log file going nuts, I could see that causing something like this.

Comment: I suggest you download  [Onyx](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx). Maybe you have heard about it: it is very useful to give maintenance to you mac. Hope it helps :/

Comment: Tried Onyx, but not even that helped.  was able to back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what you've already done, temporarily move any system wide startup items from /MacintoshHD/Library/StartupItems using Finder.

If you have done this, and removed startup items from your own account, repaired the disk, then there is really nothing else that should be slowing down the startup.

If you cannot log in to your profile, you may need to start in safe mode (hold down shift whilst booting).

Comment: After much struggle, booted into safe mode, backed up what I needed and reinstalled.